# JavaFX TableView Context menu get the selected ID

Tags: javafx

I have a TableView where I display data from my database. The TableView itself is not hard-coded on a specific table but it adds the columns and the data instead. I added Context menu, so when the user right clicks on an item, it deletes it. It works fine but I don't know how to get the ID which is the first column. Note that I don't want the selected index but the ID from the tableView (first column).

#### The questioned snippet:

```
removeMenuItem.setOnAction(event -> {
    System.out.println(row.getItem()); // HERE

    this.tableView.getItems().remove(row.getItem());
});
```

Basically, `row.getItem()` returns the record:

```
[2, Name, Stuff, Test Test, Category]
```

The question is how do I get the ID (in this case 2) or the name?

#### Full code:

```
package controllers;

import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.util.Callback;

import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class TableController {

    @FXML
    private Label descriptionLabel;

    @FXML
    private TableView tableView;

    public void setTableResultSet(String label, ResultSet resultSet) throws SQLException {
        // Create context menu
        createContextMenu();

        // Set label text
        descriptionLabel.setText(label);

        // Resolve columns
        ObservableList<ObservableList> data = resolveTableColumns(resultSet);

        // Add records
        addTableRecords(resultSet, data);
    }

    /**
     * Create a context menu responsible for removing items.
     */
    private void createContextMenu() {
        tableView.setRowFactory(tableView -> {
            final TableRow row = new TableRow();
            final ContextMenu contextMenu = new ContextMenu();
            final MenuItem removeMenuItem = new MenuItem("Remove");
            removeMenuItem.setOnAction(event -> {
                System.out.println(row.getItem()); // HERE

                this.tableView.getItems().remove(row.getItem());
            });
            contextMenu.getItems().add(removeMenuItem);

            // Set context menu on row, but use a binding to make it only show for non-empty rows:
            row.contextMenuProperty().bind(
                    Bindings.when(row.emptyProperty())
                            .then((ContextMenu) null)
                            .otherwise(contextMenu)
            );

            return row;
        });
    }

    /**
     * Resolves table columns based on a ResultSet.
     *
     * @param resultSet the ResultSet.
     * @return
     * @throws SQLException
     */
    private ObservableList<ObservableList> resolveTableColumns(ResultSet resultSet) throws SQLException {
        ObservableList<ObservableList> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        for (int i = 0; i < resultSet.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); i++) {
            final int j = i;
            TableColumn col = new TableColumn(resultSet.getMetaData().getColumnName(i + 1));
            col.setCellValueFactory((Callback<TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<ObservableList, String>, ObservableValue<String>>) param -> {
                return new SimpleStringProperty(param.getValue().get(j).toString());
            });
            tableView.getColumns().add(col);
        }
        return data;
    }

    /**
     * Adds table data from a ResultSet.
     *
     * @param resultSet the ResultSet.
     * @param data      the data.
     * @throws SQLException
     */
    private void addTableRecords(ResultSet resultSet, ObservableList<ObservableList> data) throws SQLException {
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            ObservableList<String> row = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
            for (int i = 1; i <= resultSet.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); i++) {
                row.add(resultSet.getString(i));
            }
            data.add(row);
        }
        tableView.setItems(data);
    }
}
```

**Edit based on @James_D's comment:**

```
package controllers;

import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.util.Callback;

import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class TableController {

    @FXML
    private Label descriptionLabel;

    @FXML
    private TableView<ObservableList<String>> tableView;

    public void setTableResultSet(String label, ResultSet resultSet) throws SQLException {
        // Create context menu
        createContextMenu();

        // Set label text
        descriptionLabel.setText(label);

        // Resolve columns
        ObservableList<ObservableList<String>> data = resolveTableColumns(resultSet);

        // Add records
        addTableRecords(resultSet, data);
    }

    /**
     * Create a context menu responsible for removing items.
     */
    private void createContextMenu() {
        tableView.setRowFactory(tableView -> {
            final TableRow<ObservableList<String>> row = new TableRow<>();
            final ContextMenu contextMenu = new ContextMenu();
            final MenuItem removeMenuItem = new MenuItem("Изтрий");
            removeMenuItem.setOnAction(event -> {
                System.out.println(row.getItem().get(1));

                this.tableView.getItems().remove(row.getItem());
            });
            contextMenu.getItems().add(removeMenuItem);

            // Set context menu on row, but use a binding to make it only show for non-empty rows:
            row.contextMenuProperty().bind(
                    Bindings.when(row.emptyProperty())
                            .then((ContextMenu) null)
                            .otherwise(contextMenu)
            );

            return row;
        });
    }

    /**
     * Resolves table columns based on a ResultSet.
     *
     * @param resultSet the ResultSet.
     * @return
     * @throws SQLException
     */
    private ObservableList<ObservableList<String>> resolveTableColumns(ResultSet resultSet) throws SQLException {
        ObservableList<ObservableList<String>> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        for (int i = 0; i < resultSet.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); i++) {
            final int j = i;
            TableColumn col = new TableColumn(resultSet.getMetaData().getColumnName(i + 1));
            col.setCellValueFactory((Callback<TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<ObservableList, String>, ObservableValue<String>>) param -> {
                return new SimpleStringProperty(param.getValue().get(j).toString());
            });
            tableView.getColumns().add(col);
        }
        return data;
    }

    /**
     * Adds table data from a ResultSet.
     *
     * @param resultSet the ResultSet.
     * @param data      the data.
     * @throws SQLException
     */
    private void addTableRecords(ResultSet resultSet, ObservableList<ObservableList<String>> data) throws SQLException {
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            ObservableList<String> row = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
            for (int i = 1; i <= resultSet.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); i++) {
                row.add(resultSet.getString(i));
            }
            data.add(row);
        }
        tableView.setItems(data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Start by not using raw types. E.g. your data are represented as `ObservableList<ObservableList>` (so each row is an `ObservableList`). From your `addTableRecords` method I can see that you're putting `String`s into each element of each row, so the row should be an `ObservableList<String>` and the data should be an `ObservableList<ObservableList<String>>`. Then you should have `TableView<ObservableList<String>>` and `TableColumn<ObservableList<String>, String>`, etc. If the id is the first element of the row, you can then do `row.getItem().get(0)`.

Comment: Thanks @James_D, can you confirm that I did everything okay based on your comment (check the question). Also submit that as an answer, so I can accept it.

Comment: Nearly. You still have raw `TableColumn`s in your `resolveTableColumns()` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use raw types: that way you can access the appropriate methods for the data you retrieve from the table (without have to downcast anywhere).

Specifically, you declare you represent your data as an
`ObservableList<ObservableList>`, which means that each row is represented as a (raw) `ObservableList`. Since, looking at your `addTableRecords` method, each element of a row is a `String`, the rows should be represented as `ObservableList<String>`, and the overall data as `ObservableList<ObservableList<String>>`.

The `TableView` and associated UI elements should also be parameterized: i.e. you should be using

- `TableView<ObservableList<String>>`
- `TableColumn<ObservableList<String>, String>`
- `TableRow<ObservableList<String>`

If you make these changes, then in your `createContextMenu()` method you will have

```
TableRow<ObservableList<String>> row = new TableRow<>();
```

Consequently the return type of `row.getItem()` will be `ObservableList<String>` and you can call methods defined in `ObservableList` (or more generally, `List`) on the returned value. Specifically, calling `get(...)` will return the `String` in a given cell in the row:

```
String id = row.getItem().get(0);
String name = row.getItem().get(1);
```

etc.

Put all together, this looks like

```
package controllers;

import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.util.Callback;

import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class TableController {

    @FXML
    private Label descriptionLabel;

    @FXML
    private TableView<ObservableList<String>> tableView;

    public void setTableResultSet(String label, ResultSet resultSet) throws SQLException {
        // Create context menu
        createContextMenu();

        // Set label text
        descriptionLabel.setText(label);

        // Resolve columns
        ObservableList<ObservableList<String>> data = resolveTableColumns(resultSet);

        // Add records
        addTableRecords(resultSet, data);
    }

    /**
     * Create a context menu responsible for removing items.
     */
    private void createContextMenu() {
        tableView.setRowFactory(tableView -> {
            final TableRow<ObservableList<String>> row = new TableRow<>();
            final ContextMenu contextMenu = new ContextMenu();
            final MenuItem removeMenuItem = new MenuItem("Изтрий");
            removeMenuItem.setOnAction(event -> {
                String id = row.getItem().get(0);
                String name = row.getItem().get(1);
                // do whatever you need with id and name, etc.

                this.tableView.getItems().remove(row.getItem());
            });
            contextMenu.getItems().add(removeMenuItem);

            // Set context menu on row, but use a binding to make it only show for non-empty rows:
            row.contextMenuProperty().bind(
                    Bindings.when(row.emptyProperty())
                            .then((ContextMenu) null)
                            .otherwise(contextMenu)
            );

            return row;
        });
    }

    /**
     * Resolves table columns based on a ResultSet.
     *
     * @param resultSet the ResultSet.
     * @return
     * @throws SQLException
     */
    private ObservableList<ObservableList<String>> resolveTableColumns(ResultSet resultSet) throws SQLException {
        ObservableList<ObservableList<String>> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        for (int i = 0; i < resultSet.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); i++) {
            final int j = i;
            TableColumn<ObservableList<String>, String> col = new TableColumn<>(resultSet.getMetaData().getColumnName(i + 1));
            col.setCellValueFactory(param -> 
                new SimpleStringProperty(param.getValue().get(j))
            );
            tableView.getColumns().add(col);
        }
        return data;
    }

    /**
     * Adds table data from a ResultSet.
     *
     * @param resultSet the ResultSet.
     * @param data      the data.
     * @throws SQLException
     */
    private void addTableRecords(ResultSet resultSet, ObservableList<ObservableList<String>> data) throws SQLException {
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            ObservableList<String> row = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
            for (int i = 1; i <= resultSet.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); i++) {
                row.add(resultSet.getString(i));
            }
            data.add(row);
        }
        tableView.setItems(data);
    }
}
```